# python decimal place changes after 0

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, decimal

**hello,**
i am new one in programming
i am sending a request from postman with payload

```
{"member_id":10,"value": 30.00}
```

> but when i receiving it in api by using request.data

```
{'member_id': 10, 'value': 30.0}
```

> the decimal place changes to 1 position after zero
> but i need same decimal values as sending in request which i need to verify signature.

thanks

Comment: What are you printing here? If it's a dictionary you should get consistent formatting of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing:

```
>>> price = 30.00
>>> print(price)
30.0
>>> price == 30.00
True
>>>
```

If you want the format to be retained you can use an [f string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) command:

```
f'{price:.2f}'
'30.00'
>>>
```

If you're worried about transferring numeric values in JSON then you could use strings to eliminate any loss of precision.

[This](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#:%7E:text=JSON%20does%20not%20have%20distinct,the%20same%20value%20in%20JSON.) might give some more background.

Answer (score -1):

the value should be the same because what changes is just the printing format. If you need to print the number as a string with 2 decimals, you can use

```py
value = 30.0
formated_value = '{0:.2f}'.format(value)
```